# Remove Ribbon with &InitialTabID=Ribbon.Read inside Page Viewer Web Part

Tags: url, sharepoint-on-prem, display-form, page-viewer-web-part

When I add `&IsDlg=1&InitialTabID=Ribbon.Browse` to the `Dispform.aspx` url, I only see the column names and content. The `&IsDlg=1` removes the navigation etc. and `&InitialTabID=Ribbon.Read` removes the Ribbon. That is exactly what I want. So far, so good...

But, when I add the exact same url to a Page Viewer Web Part, the navigation etc. is still removed, but the Ribbon is still there (in the Page Viewer Web Part). I don't understand why. Could anyone explain this behaviour, and even better - let me know how I get rid of the Ribbon in the Page Viewer web part in an easy way?

Comment: I have tried directly in sharepoint URL with &IsDlg=1&InitialTabID=Ribbon.Read ,.but not working .. ribbon is still there ..

Comment: My fault, it's a typo. The correct url should be DispForm.aspx?ID=1&IsDlg=1&InitialTabID=Ribbon.Browse

Comment: @JennyFergéus: it doesn't work for me too, either `Ribbon.Browse` or `Ribbon.Read`

Comment: @Kai, but did you get it to work in the dispform.aspx? Because it works perfectly there for me. I just can't figure out why it won't work in the Page Viewer WP in the default.aspx page. Really frustrating!

Comment: It doesn't work for me on dispform, ribbon is always visible no matter which query string I'm using

Comment: I found that `InitialTabID=Ribbon.Read` is used to open page with default Browse tab ribbon..

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work for me. `InitialTabID=Ribbon.Browse` works, but only in dispform directly, not when I add the dispform.aspx url to a page viewer web part.